# swapping the image when the div is clicked after changing the image with fade effect when hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a div, which changes the image on hover.
I want the div img to be changed with fade effect on hover, but when it's clicked i want the image to be changed to another image again. 
I have the below codes, and it sort of works. when the image is clicked it changes to the image i want but when it's on hover, it changes back, with fade effect to the previous image. can anyone help?

### HTML

```
<div id="mydiv_01"><img src="images/myimage_01.png" style="position:absolute;" id="my    image_01"/>
<img src="images/myimage_02.png" style="position:absolute;display:none;" id="myimage_02"   alt=""/></div>
```

### JavaScript

```
$("#mydiv_01").hover(function() {
  $("#mydiv_01 img").fadeToggle('medium');
});


$("#mydiv_01").click(function(){
$("#mydiv_01 img").attr('src','images/myimage_03');
});
```

Comment: Can you clarify what's happening a bit? When you click, it's changing to `myimage_03` as you expect, but what is it you expect with hover?

Comment: i have two absolute positioned images(my image_01&02) in mydiv_01. one of them's display is hidden. then on hover, i made it to fadeToggle so it reveals the hidden image with fadeeffect. but when I click  mydiv_01 I want the image to be changed to my image_03 and stay as it is without changing back to my image_02 when hovered.

Comment: I noticed you edited he question, but I'm afraid I don't quite follow still. 

From your code, if you over, it toggles between myimage_01 and myimage_02. But if you click, it changes BOTH images to myimage_03, so after that, the hovering shouldn't work at all... 

Am I missing something?

Comment: it changes back to my image_02 on hover, and I don't want that to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some of the actions you want separated into functions as follows:

```
reset();

function reset() {
    $('#myimage_01').attr('src', 'images/myimage_01.png');
    $('#myimage_02').attr('src', 'images/myimage_02.png');
    $("#mydiv_01").hover(function () {
        $("#mydiv_01 img").fadeToggle('medium');
    });
    setClick();
}

function setClick() {
    $("#mydiv_01").click(function () {
        $("#mydiv_01 img").attr('src', 'images/myimage_03');
        $(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
        $(this).click(function () {
            reset();
        });
    });
}
```

The `reset()` at the beginning is basically setting your images back to the originals and binding your hover functions and click functions. But the click function `setClick()` changes your images to the third one and binds a new click function that resets again when you click the third image.

Comment: how do you bind it again if you click my image_03?

Comment: Ok, so when it's clicked the first time, all the images are set to `image_03` and the hover is disabled. Now when you click `image_03`, you can bind another hover event like the first time with `$("#mydiv_01").hover(...)`, but what would you like the behavior to be then...?

Comment: I see. I want to repeat the same behavior. so it goes back to where it started.

Comment: $("#mydiv_01").click(function() {
      $("#mydiv_01 img").attr('src','images/myimage_03');
   $('#mydiv_01').unbind('hover');
   });
   $("#mydiv_01").click(function() {
    $("#mydiv_01").attr('src','images/myimage_01.png');
     });
   $("#mydiv_01").hover(function() {
      $("#mydiv img").fadeToggle('medium');
   });

Comment: First, I'm not sure `unbind('hover')` works. You might have to stick to `unbind('mouseenter mouseleave')`. 

I've updated my answer to include what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code once you click on div,the image src will get cgange to myimage_03,if you again bind hover it will show same image on hover.
 *****$("#mydiv_01 img").attr('src','images/myimage_03');*****

it will change all div images to myimage_03.